# php sort not working as expected?

Tags: php, sorting, csv

I need to get the difference between two CSV files, whereby the latest file in this case file2.csv overwrites rows with same values with an updated version and removes rows with identical data.

file1.csv

```
GHI, 0, 0
ABC, 12, 1
DEF, 10, 1
```

file2.csv

```
ABC, 8, 1
DEF, 10, 1
GHI, 2, 0
```

The final CSV should be like this :

```
ABC, 8, 1
GHI, 2, 0
```

the php code:

```
<?php
    $file1 = file('file1.csv');
    $file2 = file('file2.csv');

    sort($file1);
    sort($file2);

    var_dump($file1);
    var_dump($file2);

    $diff =  array_diff($file2, $file1);

    var_dump($diff);

    ?>
```

returns this

```
ABC, 8, 1
DEF, 10, 1
GHI, 2, 0
```

Now when I change manually file1.csv to this:

```
ABC, 12, 1
DEF, 10, 1
GHI, 0, 0
```

it returns this as expected:

```
ABC, 8, 1
GHI, 2, 0
```

When I dump the sorted array it seems the sort function works as it returns just like when I change the order manually

```
ABC, 12, 1
DEF, 10, 1
GHI, 0, 0
```

Yet it seems not to produce the same end result.  Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file` splits the file into lines, but each line still has its ending newline character. The last line, however, does not. Therefore, it is not equal to the same line contents in the middle of a file.

To fix this, you can either add a newline to the last element:

```
$file1[count($file1)-1] .= PHP_EOL;
$file2[count($file2)-1] .= PHP_EOL;
```

Or you could strip them from all the lines:

```
array_walk($file1,function(&$a) {$a = trim($a);});
array_walk($file2,function(&$a) {$a = trim($a);});
```

Comment: That too. I didn't know about that flag XD

Comment: Thank you I just looped over the values and noticed the missing newline, of course the dump didn't showed that.  Thanks

Comment: @Kolink add FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES into your answer, as deceze mentioned.